# How to identify at Php Server , application is delete from the iphone which is using push notification servies

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

i am using push notification based service in iphone application. now i want to identify that if the application is delete from the iphone device then with the help of feedback services of APNS.
now APNS is well known that application is deleted from the device, but problem is that how to we identify at Php server (php end) is that application is delete from the device.

please provide solution if it is posible.

thanks in advance

Comment: how to get error type response at php server end from APNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a push notification can not be delivered, Apple sends a feedback message via the [Feedback Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3). The Feedback Service returns json payloads with timestamp and pushtoken. These payloads are hints that the user might have uninstalled the app but it's not 100% certain. Indeed, the Feedback message will also warn you if a notification could not be delivered for temporary reasons (such as the user not having any data network available, is in Airplane mode, or disabled Notifications from your app). Therefore, I would recommend you log all of the errors that are returned from the Feedback Service and then decide on a rule that you think best identifies an uninstallation. For example, if a user is not able to receive 5 different push notifications over 1 week of time, then you might want to consider him as uninstalled or, at the very least, unreachable.